# error in program(TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python

```
s = list[4, 5, 67, 11]

def myprim(s, i=0, j=len(s)):
    while(i < j):
        for a in range(2, s(j)):
            if((s[i] % a) == 0):
                print("number is not prime " + s[i])
                j += 1
            break

    else:
        print("not prime")

myprim(s)
```

Comment: `s=list[4,5,67,11]` -> `s = [4, 5, 67, 11]` Also, `j=len(s)` isn't the best idea...

Comment: You also have indentation problems with the code. Python is very sensitive to indentation errors.

Comment: why `j+=1` inside for loop. You are not using `j` there or anywhere else after.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention is here on your first line:

```
s=list[4,5,67,11]
```

the `list` is a type in python. It seems that you want this:

```
s = [4, 5, 67, 11]
```